# android: simple service with location manager

Tags: android, service

I want a simple service without Binder. Just start the service at boot time and no destroy of the service.
I have build a Service with a location manager. But the service does not start. What ist wrong?

```
public class WayService extends Service implements LocationListener {

blabla
...

    public WayService(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) { //! hinzugefuegt
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                time = location.getTime();
                                speed = location.getSpeed();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

blabla
...

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = getLatitude();
        double longitude = getLongitude();
        String mlat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String mlon = String.valueOf(longitude);
        new PostData().execute(mlat, mlon, mtime);
    }
```

The Manifest looks like this:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".WayService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </service>


        <receiver android:name="WayStartServiceReceiver" >
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

And:

```
public class WayStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, WayService.class);
        context.startService(service);
      }
    }
```

here is my logfile:

```
01-09 13:35:29.317: D/dalvikvm(452): newInstance failed: no <init>()
01-09 13:35:29.337: D/AndroidRuntime(452): Shutting down VM
01-09 13:35:29.337: W/dalvikvm(452): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service de.app.trackmyway.WayService: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.app.trackmyway.WayService
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1929)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.app.trackmyway.WayService
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1926)
01-09 13:35:29.367: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: did you tried it by passing the context as a argument in the getLocation() method .. like  getLocation(context);

Comment: when I start the service like that in a Activity:
gps = new WayService(this);
then it works...

Comment: that will work like normal constructor not as a service..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope We cannot create the constructor in Android service. Like we cannot create the constructor in our Activity. we will be having our default override method as follow.

```
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

else try to use **oncreate** in Service class. in the **on-create** call the method **getLocation();** If you will try with the oncreate means surely it will work. you wont get any issue.

Comment: like that:
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     getLocation();
    }

Comment: yes... in that you can pass context also.. after assigning context value

Comment: ok I try it like that:
    public void onCreate(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    } this works in the virtual device manager

Comment: if it helped you acccept it

Answer (score 0):

you need to register intent filter, its more like telling receiver that it needs to listen to which broadcast

```
  <receiver android:name="WayStartServiceReceiver" >

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also the application should be installed on internal memory.

EDIT:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-beginners/B_lTmXcfo6A

Instead of using constructor, you should do some thing like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // Task to be done on first service start
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // Task to be done on each intent received.
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I try it. when I test ist with eclipse and the AVD it gives no error, but when I test it on my mobile it crashed

Comment: logs for same will help to determine what goes wrong on device. Could be due to android versions or some claws in service.

Comment: here the log:
01-08 13:13:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service de.app.trackmyway.WayService: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.app.trackmyway.WayService

Comment: ok, now I have no more errors, the service is "running" I can see it in settings application.
But nothing happens! The onLocationChanged does not start new PostData().execute(mlat, mlon, mtime); at the last line of my script